# NiFi ExecuteGroovyScript unable to resolve class JSch

Tags: groovy, apache-nifi

The groovyscript below is used to get file from remote machine using sftp. I need to get the file using sftp

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
import com.jcraft.jsch.*

java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties()
config.put "StrictHostKeyChecking", "no"

JSch ssh = new JSch()
def rfile = "/path/to/remote/file/on/remote/host";
Session sess = ssh.getSession 'user','host', 22
sess.with {
setConfig config
setPassword password
connect()
Channel chan = openChannel "sftp"
chan.connect()
ChannelSftp sftp = (ChannelSftp) chan;

def flowFile = session.get()
if(!flowFile) return
flowFile.write{rawIn, rawOut->
    def keyValueList = rawIn.withReader("UTF-8"){ new JsonSlurper().parse(it) }
    sftp.get("rfile/abc.txt").withReader("UTF-8"){reader->
        rawOut.withWriter("UTF-8"){writer->
            reader.eachLine{line->
               keyValueList.each{ if(it.Key) line = line.replaceAll(it.Key, it.Value) }
               writer << line << '\n'
            }
        }
    }
}
chan.disconnect()
disconnect()
REL_SUCCESS << flowFile
}
```

Getting error:

```
 unable to resolve class JSch @ line 7, column 6. JSch ssh = new JSch()  org.codehaus.groovy.syntax.SyntaxException
```

I am using import `import com.jcraft.jsch.*`  but it seems JSch class is not available or import is not proper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to download jsch libraries from http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/ and put jars into nifi/lib directory

or if your nifi server has access to internet you could use this script annotation to download library from public repository

```
@Grab(group='com.jcraft', module='jsch', version='0.1.55')
import com.jcraft.jsch.*
...
```

Comment: Yes the library was missing. Thanks. I thought PutSFTP internally uses com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.put ,  so this library would be available

Comment: it's uses sshj   https://github.com/apache/nifi/blob/aa741cc5967f62c3c38c2a47e712b7faa6fe19ff/nifi-nar-bundles/nifi-standard-bundle/nifi-standard-processors/src/main/java/org/apache/nifi/processors/standard/util/SFTPTransfer.java#L83

Comment: even so, libraries inside nar (nifi processor bundles) are not directly accessible through runtime classpath. each bundle has own classloader and limited libraries. you can see it in  `nifi/work/nar/extensions` subfolders. you could use those libraries through executegroovyscript - additional classpath - but i'm not recommending this.